# Can a 555 output be made to pull to ground?

Tags: microcontroller, 555

I have design in Multisim with a  555 timer that I want to pull to ground when the signal changes. It's a missing pulse detector for resetting an mcu.

Is there anyway I can achieve this with say a transistor or mosfet?

I need it to pull to ground so i can reset a MCU.

[image]

Comment: What is your MCU ? Can't 0.7 V above ground reset your MCU ?

Comment: Arduino. I'm not sure.

Comment: Look at [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels), voltage between 0 - 1.5 volt is considered logic low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CMOS version of IC 555 (LM555,.. for example). It will swing down to ground and up to VCC.

Or you can do this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fufCtK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vcc depends on your MCU voltage and M1,M2 should be logic-level MOSFETs.

Comment: If i'm reading this correctly this will flip the output from the 555 and then pull it to ground, correct?

Also, where can I learn about the cmos 555 pulling to GND when output is low?

Comment: I found in second paragraph in the datasheet.
https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icm7/icm7555-56.pdf

Comment: No, it doesn't flip the output.

Comment: ICM7555, they are a variant of CMOS 555.

Comment: I'm confused then, why use two MOSFETS then if it's not to flip the output? When gate on M2 is 'high" M1's gate will be pull to ground, and vice versa... I admit I'm still young to this but that's what I see here.

Comment: Each stage is inverting, inverting + inverting = non inverting.